# What's a good way to make parent div height reflect padding/border/margin of child div?

Tags: css, layout, html

**Background**

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        I'm the child!
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the parent div to be positioned relative to the bottom of the page as with the css properties `position: absolute`, `bottom: 0px`.

This works fine if the child div(s) have no padding or border.  However, as showcased in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YYQCP/), if the child has padding or a border, it expands beyond the bottom of the parent div (notice the rendered page is scrollable and there is additional content from the child div below the bottom of the page).

**Question**

What's the best way to make sure the parent div fully encompasses the child div vertically? (Correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't appear to be a problem with horizontal padding/borders)

My best idea was to add the sum of the padding/border/margin of to the padding to the parent div.  Using something like SASS to generate the actual css makes this slightly more palatable, but still seems like a really unclean solution.  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

(As a side note, when I made the JSFiddle example I noticed the right border was missing on the child div.  Is this just a fluke with JSFiddle or something?)

Comment: I don't think that what you are trying to achieve can be done with padding or margin. These have different purposes. The fact that the padding goes over the parent div is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of those `display: inline;`s it will work like a charm.

Comment: The key seems to be removing the `display: inline;` of the child... even after looking at documentation for `display`, I'm not sure why this works.  From what I understand, inline should just make it take up the width of the parent and be preceded and followed by line breaks...  Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Seems like what you're talking about is display: block, which is the default for div elements anyway. You should read about block and inline elements and the box model. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html , http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/cssspacing.html , and http://google.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm familiar with the box model, a little less so with display, but I've done my reading.  As I said, I'm still unclear as to why `display: block` would be more 'form fitting' in this case.

Comment: display: block = 'should just make it take up the width of the parent and be preceded and followed by line breaks'

Comment: For a good introduction to positioning: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/